# Brackets and w3c Validator said there was an error in this code

Tags: html

Brackets and w3c validator said there was an error in that closing p tag and I can not figure out what is is, please help!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="text-caramel">The following restaurants are currently serving our spirits:</h2>
            <p class="lead" style="padding-top:10px;">
                <h3>Bar Del Corso</h3>
                <a href="http://www.bardelcorso.com/" target="_blank">http://www.bardelcorso.com/</a>
            </p>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the exact error message you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--  H3 Tag Not Allow In P Tag
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2 class="text-caramel">The following restaurants are currently serving our spirits:</h2>
 <h3>Bar Del Corso</h3>
                <p class="lead" style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <a href="http://www.bardelcorso.com/" target="_blank">http://www.bardelcorso.com/</a>
                </p> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```